# Double pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++, c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic, double-pointer

I have a 2D matrix

```
matrix[m][n];
```

I know that matrix is a double pointer with type `int**`. I would like to obtain a double pointer pointing to a submatrix of the original matrix. For example, I want the submatrix to start for cell (1,1). How do I get such a double pointer from the original matrix[m][n]?

Comment: *I know that matrix is a double pointer with type int*** That is not true. You need to step back a little and understand the difference between a 2D array and a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Thanks all for clarifying the notion of array and pointer. I should have worded it better. The conclusion is that we could not achieve the goal with pointer arithmetic.

Comment: A "double pointer" is not a thing in C or C++. What you're playing with here is a "pointer to pointer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A matrix defined as 2D array of constant size:

```
int matrix [m][n];
```

is stored as m contiguous blocks of n elements. You can therefore imagine this technically as a flat sequence of m*n elements in memory. You can use pointer arithmetic to find the start of a row, or to find a specific element. But you can't locate a submatrix int that way.

The "double" pointer:

```
int **pmatrix;
```

obeys a different logic: it is a pointer to a pointer and works as an array of m pointers pointing at lines of n consecutive elements. So your elements are not necessarily consecutive. You can  use pointer arithmetic and indirection to locate the start of a row or a specific item. But again this can't address a submatrix.

Both matrix and pmatrix can be used with 1D or 2D indexing, but the compiler generates different code to address the elements.

For getting sub-matrices you have to make iterations to find the right elements, using vertical and horizontal offsets, but you can't imagine to pass somehow a pointer to the sub-matrix if you don't copy the right elements in a new matrix of target's size.

Answer (score 4):

> I know that matrix is a double pointer with type int**.

No, you don't.  Arrays are not pointers.  If you declared it as `int matrix[m][n];`, then the type of the *expression* `matrix` is `int [m][n]`; unless `matrix` is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it will have its type converted ("decay") to `int (*)[n]` (pointer to `n`-element array of `int`).

The problem is that you can't create arbitrary submatrices by just declaring a pointer of the right type; C and C++ don't provide an easy way to "slice" arrays this way.  You can certainly create a pointer of type `int (*)[n-1]` and assign the value of `&matrix[1][1]` to it (with an appropriate cast), but it won't do what you want.

**EDIT**

Now that I have a real keyboard in front of me I can expand on this a little bit.

Let's imagine a 3x3 matrix declared as follows:

```
int m[3][3] = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8}};
```

We normally visualize such a matrix as

```
+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
+---+---+---+
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
+---+---+---+
| 6 | 7 | 8 |
+---+---+---+
```

In C and C++, 2-dimensional arrays are laid out in *row-major* order<sup>1, 2</sup>, so the above matrix would be represented in memory as

```
   +---+
m: | 0 | m[0][0]
   +---+
   | 1 | m[0][1]
   +---+
   | 2 | m[0][2]
   +---+
   | 3 | m[1][0]
   +---+ 
   | 4 | m[1][1]
   +---+
   | 5 | m[1][2]
   +---+
   | 6 | m[2][0]
   +---+ 
   | 7 | m[2][1]
   +---+
   | 8 | m[2][2]
   +---+
```

So suppose you want the 2x2 submatrix starting at `m[1][1]`:

```
+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
+---+---+---+ 
| 3 | +---+---+
+---+ | 4 | 5 |
| 6 | +---+---+
+---+ | 7 | 8 |
      +---+---+
```

That corresponds to the following array elements:

```
   +---+
m: | 0 | m[0][0]
   +---+
   | 1 | m[0][1]
   +---+
   | 2 | m[0][2]
   +---+
   | 3 | m[1][0]
   +---+

     +---+ 
     | 4 | m[1][1]
     +---+
     | 5 | m[1][2]
     +---+

   +---+
   | 6 | m[2][0]
   +---+

     +---+ 
     | 7 | m[2][1]
     +---+
     | 8 | m[2][2]
     +---+
```

That's not a contiguous subarray within `m`, so *just* declaring a pointer and setting it to `&m[1][1]` won't do what you really want.  You'll need to create a separate matrix object and copy the elements you want to it:

```
int subm[2][2] = {{m[1][1], m[1][2]}, {m[2][1], m[2][2]}};
```

You can write a function to grab a 2x2 "slice" of your matrix like so:

```
void slice2x2( int (*mat)[3], int (*submat)[2], size_t startx, size_t starty )
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < 2; j++ )
      submat[i][j] = mat[startx + i][starty + j];
}

int main( void )
{
  int matrix[3][3] = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8}};
  int submat[2][2];

  slice2x2( matrix, submat, 1, 1 );

  // do something with submat
}
```

---

1. [Pre-publication draft of the C 2011 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), §6.2.5.1, ¶3.

   [Pre-publication draft of the C++ 2014 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf), §8.3.4, ¶9

Comment: Well, the OP did ask for an array of pointers. So they'd need an array `int* [n -1]` and assign `&matrix[i][1]` for each `0 < i < n`.  That will be a representation of a sub matrix... kind of

Comment: @StoryTeller No, the OP did not ask for that.

Comment: @Lundin, kinda did *"I would like to obtain a double pointer pointing to a submatrix of the original matrix"*

Comment: @StoryTeller A pointer to a sub-matrix would be `int (*)[n]`. Or in this case, since it is the inner-most matrix, you can just use `int*`. The OP spoke of pointer-to-pointers because they were confused.

Comment: @Lundin, and it just so happens that in their confusion they asked for something that can emulate what they hope to achieve, funny that.